# How to serve static files in pycharm when running a server

Tags: django, pycharm, django-staticfiles

If I wan't static files to be served when debugging or testing my application when I'm starting the server from terminal I would just add --insecure to runserver command.

But How to do that in the right way in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

Add the flag to "Additional options:" field when you edit the configuration for you project.